# Flink type extraction problems with custom generic class

Tags: generics, apache-flink, type-erasure

(Flink 1.3)

I have problems with type extraction:

```
The return type of function '...' could not be determined 
automatically, due to type erasure. You can give type information hints 
by using the returns(...) method on the result of the transformation 
call, or by letting your function implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' 
interface.
```

When using `DataStream<MyGenericClass<T>>` where:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> extends Tuple2<String, T> {
    ...
}
```

How can I solve the problem without the `.returns(..)` solution?
Can you give me an example on how to implement a type information factory or how to implement `ResultTypeQueryable` for `MyGenericClass`?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer : My answer is based on the assumption that you are using Java8 lambda expression*

I am not really sure, but according to the Flink documentation - this is a problem because "compilers such as the OpenJDK’s and Oracle JDK’s javac throw away all generic parameters related to Lambda Expressions. This means that types such as Tuple2 or Collector declared as a Lambda function input or output parameter will be pruned to Tuple2 or Collector in the compiled .class files, which is too little information for the Flink compiler."

According to the same Fink documentation - "Only the Eclipse JDT compiler preserves the generic type information necessary to use the entire Lambda Expressions feature type-safely."

So to solve you problem you can manually add the following information in your pom.xml, such that your maven will use Eclipse JDT compiler -

```
<!-- put these lines under "project/build/pluginManagement/plugins" of your pom.xml -->

<plugin>
  <!-- Use compiler plugin with tycho as the adapter to the JDT compiler. -->
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- This dependency provides the implementation of compiler "jdt": -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
        <version>0.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

For More information refer to this link - https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/java8.html